# Taking a Variable value from the code behind and use in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I  need to validate the textbox(quantity) where the data(quantity) from the database is stored in code behind and I have to validate the given input value with the variable value from the code behind so that the user cannot use more quantity then the value in database.

Comment: please refine your question with some details. It seems too broad as is now.

Comment: Not trying to sound like a dick, but your answer might be better interpreted if you add more detail but most of all, splitting up the sentence for better flow.

Comment: The title for this Question seemingly implies an approach to performing the validation, when code to do the validation is fairly routine.  This creates some cognitive dissonance in trying to reply, as I think a careful reading of the Answers provided indicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have a `Quantity` variable in the code behind, which holds the maximum number the user can insert, you need to add a validator to your TextBox like this:

```
<asp:RangeValidator id="Range1"
           ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
           MinimumValue="0"
           MaximumValue="<%# Quantity %>"
           Type="Integer"
           Text="Value inserted is more than the allowed maxium quantity"
           runat="server"/>
```

Comment: after using the above method i got error: The value '' of the MaximumValue property of 'range' cannot be converted to type 'Integer'.

Comment: how can i resolve this above error?

Comment: Your `Quantity` variable must be an Integer. What value does it hold?

Comment: it holds for example.. public int? quantity

Comment: In your code behind you need to define `Public int Quantity` and then assign it to the value you want.

Comment: ya @nmat i have did it...thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make that variable public or create a property which could hold value for that variable and then you could access it in aspx page like this

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <h1><%=Name%></h1>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Code behind code should be like this

```
 public string Name{ get; set; }
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Name = "Mega Mind";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from your question title, not description, that you want to access a variable in your code behind, from you client script code (that is aspx)

You can register the variable by using ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock()

More info in [enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef.aspx)